# How to give my modal function the path?

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I'm not sure how I can do this.
I have a list of delete buttons. And I have a modal.
I want to open the modal and if OK - delete.

So I get my function feedback if yes or now, but how pass I the path from the delete button?

Button:

```
<a class="ui red labeled icon button" href="#{{ path('newspaper_name_direct_delete', { 'id': newspaper_name.id }) }}">
                            <i class="icon trash"></i>
                            {{ 'authorsite.form.delete'|trans }}
```

Script:

```
$('#confirmation-modal')
        .modal({
            onApprove: function () {
                console.log('yes');
            },
            onDeny: function () {

                console.log('no');
            }
        });
```

Thanks for help,
Mike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Promises for these type of operations. Below is the code

```
$('.delete-btns').on("click", function () {

    var id = $(this).attr('record-id'); //You can use any other attibute name to get id of record

    var p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        $('#confirmation-modal').modal({
            onApprove: resolve,
            onDeny: reject
        });
    })


    p.then(function () {

        //Clicked ok

        //Code here to to delete the record

    }, function () {

        //Canceled

    })
});
```